# JSONP inner workings with AJAX

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, jsonp

I understand that the key concept behind JSONP is that `<script>` tags
are the only elements that bypass javascript same origin policy.
So using these tags we can load third party data disguised as js code.

I don't quite understand how JSONP is used in conjuction with **AJAX**.

My best guess is that:

when an AJAX call is made under the hoods a `<script> tag` elements is **actually** written in the document on the exact moment the AJAX request has to be made and therefore its result is immediately evaluated.

Can you help me with these also providing a simple example ?

thanks

Comment: I don't think my question is a duplicate. In the questio you linked there's no mention to AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works exactly the way you thought it should:

[image: JSONP via XHR]

It adds an async `script` tag into `head`, and immediately removes it after calling the callback function.

---

**Update**

Only to inform, I was using the JSONP flickr API in the example above:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?', {
      tags: 'jquery',
      tagmode: 'any',
      format: 'json'
    },
    function(data) {
      $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
        $('<img />').attr('src', item.media.m).appendTo('#images');
      });
    });
}, 2000);
```